# What kind of magic does happen in this PHP code?

Tags: php, reference, getter-setter

Anybody who knows php internals could you please explain such PHP behavior?

```
<?php

class Test {

     private $a;

     public function __get($name) {
       echo('GETTER CALLED!');
       return null;
     }

     public function testme() {
       $v = array(1, 2, 3);
       unset($this->a); // <-- this line *
       $this->a = &$v;
     }

 }

 $test = new Test();
 $test->testme();
```

When `unset($this->a)` is here (i.e. not commented out) php results in following output with errors:

```
GETTER CALLED!<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Indirect modification of overloaded property Test::$a has no effect in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object in [...][...]:15
Stack trace:
#0 [...][...](21): Test-&gt;testme()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
```

But commenting out that line seem to fix the problem so what is the reason?
The real questions are:

1. Where does "Indirect modification of overloaded property" take place?
2. "Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object" - why only after `unset`?
3. Why the getter is called at all? While it shoud not.

Comment: Let us suppose PHP version being 7.1, similar output in earlier versions down to 5.4.

Comment: i think it's because you have redifined the magic method __get(), so actually you try to unset NULL at the moment

Comment: MacBooc, we can initialize the field before doint unset but it does not change the output.

Comment: From the manual `Note:It is possible to unset even object properties visible in current context.`  Does that mean, once it's gone it's gone?

Comment: @Progrock, so why getter is called then...

Comment: If you assign a reference to any non-existing property you get the same with the __get mm in place.

Comment: i confirm what @MacBooc says, removing the overriden `_get` function makes the code work. Probably the getter is called when you try to access the value of `$a` in the `unset`

Comment: The unset is not causing the magic __get call.

Comment: @Kaddath, no, removing assignment line avoids __get call

Comment: The issue is not the unset, but the `$v` being passed by reference. I don't know exactly why, but removing the `&` makes the code run with no issues.

Comment: If you assign null to the private property instead of using unset it doesn't break..

Comment: Yes, but i reference and unset are required here. Everything is fine but that unneeded __get call.

Comment: @MikhailKarakulov can you explain WHY unset is needed when you're re-assigning it the line after? The re-assignment will just clear the previous value anyway..

Comment: @Progrock, assigning null will also nullify previous referenced field/variable that could be there. The example program is just stripped down version of a  more complex one.

Comment: @naththedeveloper  - "assigning null will also nullify previous referenced field/variable that could be there. The example program is just stripped down version of a more complex one." - I must reset reference, but keep original referenced values, in more complex, long-running applicaiton.

Comment: actually when removing reference in the assignment, the overriden `__get` is not called. It may be a side-effect of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From DoPPeS explanation, i had this working with minimal changes. I moved the creation of the array outside the class and added a getter just to verify that the assignment by reference was working.

The simple fix is that from what DoPPeS said, it has to re-create the property, but cannot assign the reference directly, using a dummy value first to create the property, it now exists and can be assigned by reference (there could be more elegant solutions, but it works):

```
<?php

class Test {

    private $a;

    public function __get($name) {
        echo('GETTER CALLED!');
        return null;
    }

    public function testme(&$val) {
        unset($this->a);
        $this->a = 'test'; // <-- creates the property
        $this->a = &$val; // <-- now reference works
    }

    public function getVal($name) {
        if(!isset($this->{$name})){
            return NULL;
        }
        return $this->{$name};
    }

}

$v = array(1, 2, 3);
$test = new Test();
$test->testme($v);
$v[] = 4;
var_dump($test->getVal('a'));

?>
```

Comment: It's interesting that property is recreated as.. private. We dynamically create private property. Okay, __get therefore was called as a side effect of reference assignment error...

Comment: @MikhailKarakulov yeah, the whole problem puzzles me a bit, but it's not the first time i see a language producing an error at an unexpected place

Answer (score 0):

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php 
and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

> Overloading in PHP provides means to dynamically "create" properties and methods. These dynamic entities are processed via magic methods one can establish in a class for various action types.

When you unset() private variable $a, it is as if it never existed, as if you never set "private $a;" at the start of your class. At line 16, PHP notices that $this->a is not set and the magic kicks in, using the __get method. You start using a overloaded property $this->a that is "magically" created.

So to answer your questions:

1. In the __get() method, if I'm not mistaken.
2. only after you use unset() because private $a is used as defined at the top of your class until you actually unset() it.
3. It should be called, as it is normal behaviour of PHP to call __get() if your class property is not set and you are setting by reference. You'll have the same result with the simplified example below:

```php
<?php

class Test {
    public function __get($name) {
        echo('GETTER CALLED!');
        return null;
    }

    public function testme() {
        $v = array(1, 2, 3);
        $this->a = &$v;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->testme();
```

Comment: __get is not called when assignment is done by value and not by reference, really __get is used for read-access to non-existent field, We don't read anything from the field. Indirect modification is also not such obvious, but it is not important. coz maybe really just a side effect

Comment: added more info to post to reflect your comments

Answer (score 0):

**Argument of magic method __get can't be passed by reference.**

Simpler code:

```
class Test {
     public function __get($name) {
       return null;
     }
 }

 $test = new Test();
 $a=1;
 $test->a=&$a; # <-- Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: How is this applicable: `Argument of magic method __get can't be passed by reference.`?

Answer (score 0):

The last question is very interesting, I get the following information through the search, hope to help you.

1. After the unset property, the attribute will not exist, so "$this->a" is "overloading".
2. > arguments of these magic methods can be passed by reference.   [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).
3. > This functionality initially looked like a bug to me, but it turned out to be expected behaviour after asking around for quite a bit. [Regression/unset properties behavior](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/228).